# How to restrict decimal in a console calculator in C#? Like when a decimal is inputted, it should print an error. But no if doesn't

Tags: c#

Can someone help me modify my work? Help me add:

- An error message when the user tries to enter decimal values.
- A third operand for the calculator.
- An error message when the user tries to enter any string value other than “exit”.

Here's my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write("x = ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            if (str == "exit")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Programme has stopped");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(str);
                Console.Write("y = ");
                int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int sum = x / y;
                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", sum);
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
}
```

I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Please NEVER show a picture of your code. Instead, copy your code as text and paste it into your question the `{}` button will format it as `code`. That way, we can copy your code and see what the issue is

Comment: I've changed it.

Comment: You are using `Convert.ToInt32`.  Consider using `int.TryParse`, or, if you want to allow `decimals` (but warn on their use), using `decimal.TryParse`.  They both allow you to check if the entered string is in the correct numeric format

Comment: Were either of the answers of use to you?  If one of them answered your question you can _Accept_ it by clicking the checkmark.  If one or both of them was of use, you can _Up-vote_ the answer (click the up arrow).  I believe, since you have so little _reputation_ that your upvote won't initially count, but once you get sufficient reputation, it will.  That's the currency on this site (accepted answers and voting).  It also makes it easier for the next person to tell what answers are useful (when someone goes searching for an issue like yours)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you can use:

```
public static bool HasDecimals(decimal x) {
    return Decimal.Round(x, 0) != x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to do this, I'd create a function that I can use to handle most of the user interaction (emitting the prompt, parsing the input string, deciding if "Exit" was entered).  In the code below, I kinda-sorta use the standard `TryGetXxx` pattern.

In this code below, if the `TryGetDecimalValueWithPrompt` returns `true`, then a properly parsed number is returned in the output.  If it returns `false`, then the user has chosen to quit.

So, I start with that function:

```
public static bool TryGetDecimalValueWithPrompt(string prompt, out decimal outputValue)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt + " > ");
        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        if (response.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || response.Equals("quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            outputValue = 0.0m;
            return false;
        }
        if (decimal.TryParse(response, out outputValue))
        {
            return true;
        }
        //otherwise, failure, so try again
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, incorrect format, try entering a correctly formatted decimal again");
    }
}
```

The `while(true)` statement says *Loop Forever*.  In this case, *Forever* lasts until the user has entered a properly formatted number or one of the "exit" keywords.

Then I construct my program around it:

```
if (!TryGetDecimalValueWithPrompt("Enter the first operand", out var operand1))
{
    return;
}

if (!TryGetDecimalValueWithPrompt("Enter the second operand", out var operand2))
{
    return;
}

if (operand2 == 0.0m)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you can't divide by zero");
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine($"The result of op1/op2 is {operand1 / operand2}");
```

If you don't want to allow decimals being entered, change the `TryGetDecimalValueWithPrompt` function to work with integers instead:

```
public static bool TryGetIntValueWithPrompt(string prompt, out int outputValue)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt + " > ");
        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        if (response.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || response.Equals("quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            outputValue = 0;
            return false;
        }
        if (int.TryParse(response, out outputValue))
        {
            return true;
        }
        //otherwise, failure, so try again
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, incorrect format, try entering a correctly formatted integer again");
    }
}
```

If you work with integers, remember that integer division always yields an integer.  For example, if you use integers in `7 / 2`, the result will be `3`, not `3.5`.  If you want `3.5`, do something like `7 / (decimal) 2` (at that point, you are dividing an integer by a decimal and you'll get a decimal).

By the way, if you wanted to prompt for the operator (`+`, `-`, `*`, or `/`), you could create a `TryGetOperator` function in the same pattern and just check whatever you get from the user with something like:

```
var operators = new[] { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
bool goodOperator = operators.Contains(inputFromUser);
```